# Trying to call bazel within CMake in execute process

Tags: cmake, bazel

I am trying to call bazel inside my cmake file in a execute process like so:

```
execute_process(
            COMMAND ${BAZEL} run
            ${TENSORFLOW_PATH} --
            --common_tflite_path=${tflite_path}
            --input_tflite_files=${tflite_file_name}
            --output_dir=${output_dir}
    )
```

but this seems to cause a problem and I have this error

```
Function invoked with incorrect arguments for function named: tensorflow build
```

Can some explain how to call bazel in CMake?

NB: I have bazel installed on my computer.